# Spring Service Garbage Collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, garbage-collection

I have a Spring `Service`, which calls an API. This `Service` creates several objects and returns these to the client (of a REST request).
Is this good practice? I observe rising memory consumption with every request. Is there is no garbage collection happening?

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service("FanService")
public class Service {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

    public List<String> allCLubsInLeague() {
        try {
            URI urlString = new URI("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php?l=German%20Bundesliga");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            TeamsList response = restTemplate.getForObject(urlString, TeamsList.class);
            List<BundesligaTeams> bundesligaTeams = response.getTeams();

            //ResponseEntity<List<BundesligaTeams>> test = t.getForEntity(urlString, BundesligaTeams.class);

            List<String> teamList = new ArrayList<>();
            bundesligaTeams.forEach(value -> teamList.add(value.getStrTeam()));
            log.info(bundesligaTeams.get(0).getStrAlternate());
            bundesligaTeams = null;
            response = null;
            urlString = null;
            restTemplate = null;

            return teamList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not coding low-latency application with zero-garbage allocation you should focus on writing readable and maintainable code first. Only then tune performance if it's not acceptable.

It's ok to create objects if you have available memory, memory allocation is cheap comparing to a GET request. See [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html).

1. There is no reason to `null` a local variable unless you are trying to remove security credentials. Don't write `bundesligaTeams = null;` and other statements at the end, these object will be collected once they are not reachable.
2. `RestTemplate` should be a separate bean. Creating this object could be expensive if the underling HTTP client creation is expensive. Consider auto-wiring the default `RestTemplate` provided by Spring Boot.
3. Cache the result of the GET request locally if the data is not changing often. A list of all the clubs in the German Bundesliga will change only once a year.
4. You should avoid creating `String` for `log.info()` call if the `info` logging level is not enabled. Either use placeholder syntax or call `log.isInfoEnabled()` before. Check out the [What is the fastest way of (not) logging?](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) FAQ.

Comment: 2. Is already provided by Spring Boot by default. 4. Doesn't really change here, as it only applies to string concat, using a placeholder will actually create 2 strings and still do no logging, the `isInfoEnabled` should not be needed with SLF4j.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any memory leak in this code.

- Your memory is raising in every request because Garbage Collector will garbage unused objects when it decides to do so. So your objects can be garbaged after 10 or 20 request - you never know.
- This happens because you still have a lot of free memory on your heap so garbage collector is not forced to clean it up yet. If you will try to invoke many many requests you will see Garbage Collector activity soon.
- If you want to see more details, you can always run `jvisualvm` which should be shipped with JDK and observe how your heap memory increase/decrease according to garbage collector activity